# How to migrate Microsoft.OneDriveSDK v1 to v2?

Tags: c#, xamarin, onedrive

I have a Xamarin based application which uses the Microsoft.OneDriveSDK nuget Package with version 1.x In this application I manage the OAuth stuff using Xamarin.Auth and thus get the access_token from that framework.

With the OneDriveSDK 1.x, I could provide this access token by redefining a few classes and then never had the API trying to fetch the token.

Now I wanted to migrate to version 2 and noticed that the previous classes got replaced and the API now uses Microsoft.Graph nuget package instead. So I had to implement the interface IAuthenticationProvider and did it like this:

```
    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MicrosoftLiveOAuthProvider.Instance.AccessToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", MicrosoftLiveOAuthProvider.Instance.AccessToken);
        }
    }
```

The code is called and properly provides the authentication token to the request headers. But once the SDK tries to use the token, I get an exception:

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' was thrown.
>
> Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
>
> Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184118

Now using google for this message always said the token is not JWT compliant and the SDK would then use it as microsoft live account token. But if this is the case, I wonder why it fails with V2 but works with V1.

Authentication is done against:

> https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf

Any help is very mich appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a subclassed Xamarin.Auth `WebRedirectAuthenticator` with `Microsoft.OneDriveSDK` v2.0.0.

I get the initial `access_token` via that `Xamarin.Auth` subclass using a `authorizeUrl:` that is built via:

```
string GetAuthorizeUrl()
{
    var requestUriStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    requestUriStringBuilder.Append(Consts.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationServiceUrl);
    requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("?{0}={1}", Consts.RedirectUriKeyName, Consts.Redirect_URI);
    requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", Consts.ClientIdKeyName, Consts.Client_ID);
    requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", Consts.ResponseTypeKeyName, Consts.TokenKeyName);
    requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", Consts.ScopeKeyName, Consts.Drive_Scopes);
    return Uri.EscapeUriString(requestUriStringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Once I have the access and refresh tokens, I can implement the `IHttpProvider` that needs passed to the `OneDriveClient` constructor in order to set access token in the http header:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    SetupHttpClient();
    return _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    SetupHttpClient();
    return _httpClient.SendAsync(request, completionOption, cancellationToken);
}

HttpClient _httpClient;
void SetupHttpClient()
{
    if (_httpClient == null)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var accessToken = _account.Properties["access_token"];
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    }
}
```

Create your `OneDriveClient` client using your `IAuthenticationProvider`  and `IHttpProvider` objects (I just implement them on the same class that I am building all the OneDrive API calls), and every OnDrive request will use the access token from your saved `Account`.

Note: My `IAuthenticationProvider` implementation of `AuthenticateRequestAsync` currently does nothing, but you could do your `Account` setup here for a cleaner code flow.

```
var oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0", this, this);
var pictureFolderItem = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("Pictures").Request().GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine(pictureFolderItem.Folder);
```

Refreshing is almost as easy, I store when the access token will expire (minus 5 minutes) and setup a timer to refresh it and re-save it to the `Account`. Do the same thing on app launch, if the user has an `Account` available and thus previously logged in, check if it is expired, refresh it, setup the background timer...

```
async Task<bool> GetRefreshToken(Account account)
{
    // https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/auth/msa_oauth.md#step-3-get-a-new-access-token-or-refresh-token
    OneDriveOAuth2Authenticator auth = OAuth2Authenticator();
    var token = account.Properties["refresh_token"];
    var expiresIn = await auth.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(token);
    ResetRefreshTokenTimer(expiresIn);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time for this comprehensive answer! Meanwhile I noticed that in the area where I registered the app for OneDrive, one can now define also Microsoft Graph permissions like delegations and app credentials. I am sure this will have to be set too. Furthermore the description there stated that the V2 Auth endpoint is either Azure AD or Microsoft Live. I am currently authenticating against Microsoft Live only, so the main advantage of MS Graph is gone.

Comment: I am only using a Live acct to oauth2 against, i wish there was a way not to use Graph with the C# OneDrive SDK like you can with their Android version. But skipping using it for login and only implement ing the two interfaces works fine. Luckily the xamarin linker strips all that unused Graph code out and the app size is managable